# Test RTMP connection like ping domain -t in CMD

Tags: actionscript-3, cmd, rtmp, flash-media-server

Is there a way to test RTMP connection like the command "ping domain -t" in CMD so that I can check how many times the RTMP server is down for a certain period of time.

Comment: Are you trying to ping from a Flash application? You can do repeated URLRequests to get a status file, if that erred, you count this as a failure. Make sure you'll not query the Web server too often.

Comment: @Vesper no, I'm not pinging from flash, but the flash, sometimes, is giving the connection status 'nc.connected == false'. That's why I'd like to know if it's really the RTMP server is failing. Thanks for your reply

Answer (score 2):

You can use [rtmpdump](https://rtmpdump.mplayerhq.hu/) and connect to a video that doesn't exist.

Such as

`rtmpdump -r rtmp://[server]/[application]/gibberish`

where `gibberish` isn't an actual video on your server.

I get back

```
Connecting ...
INFO: Connected...
ERROR: Closing connection: NetStream.Play.StreamNotFound
```

This does what you want, in that it connects to your server over RTMP and returns a "Connected" message. If your server was down, it'd give you a different error.

If you're using AMS, there's also the [Adobe Media Server Administration Console](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/adobemediaserver/configadmin/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d119f2926bcf-7ff4.2.3.html), which runs on a different port than RTMP, so unless your entire box crashes, you should be able to check and see if it's running.